How to know exactly the number of blocks created by SBM in graphtool?
I will use this graph right here as an example.
import pandas as pd
import graph_tool.all as gt
g = gt.collection.data["polbooks"]
state = gt.minimize_blockmodel_dl(g)
state.draw(pos=g.vp["pos"], vertex_shape=state.get_blocks())


As you can see only 3 blocks are formed, however when I use these commands:
state.get_B() #number of blocks

returns 105
state.get_N() #Returns the total number of nodes.

returns 105
state.get_nonempty_B()

returns 3
My question is, as I know exactly how many communities were formed, why when using the commands above do I have the number of communities formed to be 105 when we clearly see that there are only 3 and how do I get exactly which nodes are in each community?

what do you mean "3 blocks are formed" ?

That three communities were detected.

it is not obvious to me how "we clearly see that there are only 3". . . ?  i see 2 potential clusters (if that is what a community refers to).

In the image we see the coloring of three groups, so 3 communities or blocks were inferred, that's what I'm referring to. When I use state.get_B(), 105 is returned, which corresponds to the number of nodes and not the number of blocks formed represented in the figure.

as per https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/demos/inference/inference.html,
"for reasons of algorithmic efficiency, the group labels returned are not necessarily contiguous, and they may lie in any subset of the range [0,N-1], where N is the number of nodes in the network.
